# Is there anyway to point to specific position row in dbcontext?

Tags: c#, dbcontext

I know that dbcontext has FirstorDefault and LastorDefault to point to the oldest and the newest row created. But I need to know how to point to the others or specific row. What I aiming for right now is the row right above the last row. By default, data is displayed by time of their created and I intend to keep it at that.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to get, for example, the rows matching a list of IDs in a single query without changing your model to include the row ID as a field. But you can use `.OrderBy(...).Skip(...).Take(1)` patterns to get one row at a time, if you know its position with a particular sort order. You could probably even `Concat()` several of those queries together to do a single DB round-trip, but I don't know if it would perform very well.

Comment: This seems like it would be much easier to grab all the rows in question and implement which one you want yourself

Comment: `'row 4,6`' ? You mean 4 and 6? Maybe some sample data with how you would decide the rows? Otherwise, this isn't exactly answerable in a meaningful way

Comment: @AustinTFrench In SQL Server, the table usually display rows data in order of time created. Is about time created and that's all.

Comment: Yes, usually. But it is not guaranteed, so you shouldn't rely on that. Second, rows 4 and 6? `row(4, 6)` for example could denote `rows(startIndex 4, endIndex 6)` which would work perfect for `.OrderBy(o => o.CreatedTime).Skip(4).Take(3)`. Add to that, if you wanted, feed that to a List and take index 0 and 2, and you'd have 2 results.

Comment: @AustinTFrench No, I think you got me wrong. I don't want to get a list of rows. 4 and 6 here meaning that row 4 or row 6. Like if I input number 4, then row 4 data will be printed. Not from 4 to 6.

Comment: There is *no* guarantee on what row you'll retrieve if you ask for "first" or "last" and *don't* specify an ordering. Don't try to program by *coincidence* and then become surprised or alarmed when your code starts acting up because you embedded a bad assumption.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry for my lack of knowledge then. I thought that if they have FirstOrDefault, along with LastorDefault which return affectively, I thought that they also have method to point to specific position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you **need** to find a column to sort reliably on. Assuming a sort order by default work will make anywhere you need `where(expression of Index) then do (things)` will cause possible issues.

I'll assume you have a *createDate* column for the example:

```
var secondToLastRecord = fooEntities.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreateDate).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

This will give you an IQueryable of 1 record with the second to last record.

Because the newest record would be at the top of the list, which you skip. You then take (select) the 2nd record. You can then create the actual object you need with Select or First.

Comment: It work perfectly for display but I have other problem now. That 'secondToLast' won't allow me to interact with entities inside.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, exactly. Please try to isolate the problem, and ask a new question if required with exactly what the new problem might be,

Comment: I found the solution, thank you. So by your way, I can only display the second from last but can't interact with it for any other purpose. For example, I have a column called applyDate that would mean for compared with Date at the moment. I will query from the last and if the applyDate does not meet requirement, I will have to query to the one before that again and again until I found the row that satisfy requirement. In your solution, I can't interact with it at all so I can't use it to compare again or getting the data I want even if it meet the requirement.

Comment: Were you materializing the result? Regardless, it sounds like you should be using a where clause before selecting a record.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be materialized. Your answer was pretty close. Just replace Take() with FirstOrDefault then it will be available for either display or any other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referring to Linq, right?

One way is to grab everything.
Then, call .ToList() method.
At that point you can use the index in braces like [4] or [6] etc.

Example:
List cars = _context.Cars.ToList();
Car specificCar = cars[4];

Note: You will get slow performance if there is an large amount of db rows in your DbContext because the .ToList() method gets all of the rows first.

Another way is to do a .Find() method if there is some unique id like a database id, etc.

Examaple: Car specificCar =  _context.Cars.Find(f=>f.id == myUid);
if(specificCar == null) return; //would need to check for null etc.....

I think if you get a little more familiar with Linq expressions you'll find that there are multiple ways to achieve this.

.SingleOrDefault(s=>s.CarMake == make);
.Where(w=>w.CarMake == "Ferrari").ToList().. then go from there.
Etc.

Comment: Yeah, getting a full list is really hurtful. Even if your method work, I can't use it. Sorry.

Comment: Ok. how about .Find(f=>f.Id == uid) method?  If you know the primary key id this will return the specific record and return the object for that record.

Comment: No. I'm not sorting rows with id. I need to point to it by time created rows or more specific I want to point to the rows that right above the last row which also the newest row.

Comment: @FaizEming if you want the next to last row, please update your question. We need all the details to offer a decent answer!

Comment: @AustinTFrench Sorry. I thought that asking for a bigger solution would be convenience for later but only that would be okay for now. I will edit my question right away.

Comment: It's not a problem! @FaizEming, just please keep in mind how to ask a good question means things like [XY questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) means that even a good answer to what you asked, might not answer your real question.